# django 1.7 how to dynamically set the choices value of a forms.ChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.7

I created a custom `forms.ChoiceField` where in the `__init__` method, I access my model (`ModelA.objects.get_all_offers()`) from which I deduce the choices I want the form field to have.

```
qs = ModelA.objects.get_all_offers()
kwargs['choices'] = get_choices_from_qs(qs)
```

I had no problem with django 1.6 but I switched to django 1.7 and now, when I run "check", "makemigrations", or anything, I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "xxx" does not exist
```

which is related to the fact that `ModelA.objects.get_all_offers()` is executed and I guess the db is not created yet (since if I remove the query and set a static tuple, it works).

How to dynamically set the choices value of a forms.ChoiceField in django1.7?

Thanks

Comment: Where is this code located exactly?

Comment: The custom ChoiceField and the model are in the same app. Where I define my custom form field, I do ```from ..models import ModelA``` to get my Model that I use in the ```__init__``` method of the form field.

Comment: So, to answer my question, those two lines are in the init method of the form field?

Comment: Correct, I make the query in the init method of the form field and set the choices after manipulating the queryset (get_choices_from_qs method)

Comment: You are populating the `ChoiceField` with a model? Would you be better off using a `ModelChoiceField`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships

Comment: There has got to be a way to use choices to fix this. Having the same problem and don't want to use a ModelChoiceField. I'll see if I can figure it out.